# How to change the `primary color` for ThemeData dark in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am using flutter `2.8.0` to create a simple app.
But when I am trying to change the primary color for the App it does not work with me.

This is the code I am working on:

```
class BMICalculator extends StatelessWidget {
  const BMICalculator({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        primaryColor: const Color(0xFF0A0E21),
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: const Color(0xFF0A0E21),
      ),
      home: const InputPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

@Mrinal already mentioned you to use primarySwatch. Flutter team intended to build [clean up the Theme system](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1kzIOQN4QYfVsc5lMZgy_A-FWGXBAJBMySGqZqsJytcE/edit#heading=h.pub7jnop54q0) and make everything more consistent and based off of the ColorScheme colors. They recommend using color scheme instead of primary color

```
 theme: ThemeData(
     primaryColor: ColorsX.primary,
     colorScheme: ColorScheme.light().copyWith(primary: ColorsX.primary),
  );
```

For dark theme

```
theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.light().copyWith(primary: Colors.tealAccent),
        ),
```

output:

[image]

For more read this article [article](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/89839#issuecomment-919437144)

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue, but in my case I'm using the `seeds` and `useMaterial3: true`.

This solves it for me, to keep **consistency** between light and dark mode themes.

The only difference is to just add `brightness: Brightness.dark` to the seed.

```dart
return MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    useMaterial3: true,
    colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(
        seedColor: const Color(0xFF57CC99)),
  ),
  darkTheme: ThemeData(
    useMaterial3: true,
    colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(
        brightness: Brightness.dark, // <-- the only line added
        seedColor: const Color(0xFF57CC99)),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use primarySwatch

```
theme: ThemeData(
primarySwatch: Colors.red,
),
```

Comment: This is worked for me, but I need to do it with dark `ThemeData`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for me..

```
MaterialColor _primartSwatch = Colors.purple;

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'MyApp',
      themeMode: _themeMode,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: _primartSwatch,
      ),
      darkTheme: ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
        primarySwatch: _primartSwatch,
      ),
      home: SplashScreen(),
    );
  }
```